# mono/linux socket denied?

Tags: linux, sockets, mono

I am using [alchemy websockets](http://alchemywebsockets.net/) and figured out enough to get something working on windows. I built alchemy on linux (ubuntu) with mono and ran my server. It gets a socket error. The port is >1k (port 8005 to be exact)

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Access denied
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint local_end) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start (Int32 backlog) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Alchemy.TcpServer.Listen (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

From the filename it looks like i forgot to build with debug information or didnt install symbols but i did successfully build on mono. Its using .NET 4.0 mono 2.10

Why am i getting access denied on sockets?

Comment: I suggest you attach the code before and after you construct the listener.

Comment: Is your system running any [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tools such as[AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/)? Any of these can prevent a program from opening a TCP socket. Check `dmesg(1)` output or `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for messages that look like MAC rejection / denied notices.

Comment: @sarnold: I see AppArmor mention in dmesg. I didnt realize i had that. After running monodevelop/my app with sudo i can run the server but the client (firefox+javascript) behaves wrong. It doesnt seem to notice my server connecting

Comment: Does `sudo aa-status` show your `mono` or program is confined? Does `dmesg | grep 'apparmor="DENIED"` show anything denied for your program or browser?

Comment: @sarnold: I'm not sure. I can tell you that the socket is not longer being denied BUT in firefox (both on the linux VM and windows which is the host) closes their connection and doesnt appear to get a connection. My app logs the connection attempt. Maybe this lib isnt supported on mono/linux

Comment: Which version of Firefox? The Alchemy Websockets webpage has a link to Wikipedia's list of which browsers support which versions of Websockets, and Firefox 11 or newer is required for the RFC version. Their website also specifically mentions Mono, which is promising.

Comment: @sarnold: firefox 11 and whichever version of chrome is available for download last week. It may be my linux distro but i have no other to test with ATM

Comment: Okay, try including some source code and maybe someone will be able to spot the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check out

`netstat -a | grep 8005` See if something else is using port 8005

Run as su to see if it's a permission problem

`sudo mono YourProgram.exe`

I didn't take a good look at the library you are using, but if it uses ICMP or Raw Sockets it has to run as root.

Another thing to look at is to see if the DNS resolution you are using matches. Sandboxed runtimes normally only complain about this, but I've seen stranger things happen and you haven't given us much information to go on.

If it is a root problem and not that another program is using port 8005 you might be able to get away with using `setcap` on the mono binary so you don't have to run it as root.

Run this as root:
`setcap cap_net_raw=iep /path/to/mono`

Comment: There really should be no need to run mono with `cap_net_raw` capability to bind port `8005`. You might be right that raw or ICMP might require something different, but at least the stack trace is showing `TcpServer` and `Listen`, both good indicators that it is TCP.

Comment: @sarnold I 100% agree. But with little information is being provided I'm kind of throwing things against the wall to see what sticks.

Answer (score 0):

As answered at [Access denied for Alchemy WebSocket creation in Linux/Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380411/access-denied-for-alchemy-websocket-creation-in-linux-mono#comment16913395_12380411)

> Alchemy throws up a Flash Policy file at 843 - try turning off the flashsocketpolicy when instantiating your server.

Comment: I dont exactly understand. I dont have flash installed on my debian webserver (its doesnt have a gui/window system. It only has shell access). But I believe i went with another solution. This was for a prototype project

Comment: It's not about having flash on the server. The server serves an XML file that a flash client needs to connect (if you, for example, tried to connect to the server through a browser using flash.)

Comment: Oh. I was just using straight javascript (client side). No flash was involved in client nor server

Comment: Right. That's why you should disable the flash socket policy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set the capabilities to the mono binary.

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/mono-sgen
```