# Access denied for Alchemy WebSocket creation in Linux/Mono

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, mono

My question is virtually identical to [mono/linux socket denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254954/mono-linux-socket-denied) but it doesn't seem that question was ever properly answered so I'm still stuck.

I have a server written using Alchemy WebSockets. I had it working fine on Windows but after porting it to Linux I can't get it to work. I get the following error every time I try to start up the socket server:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Access denied
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint local_end) [0x00051] in /build/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1104
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start (Int32 backlog) [0x00022] in /build/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/TcpListener.cs:268
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start () [0x00000] in /build/src/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/TcpListener.cs:243
  at Alchemy.TcpServer.Listen (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'm trying to bind to a port above 1024 (specifically 12345 in this case) so that's not the issue. I'm not running AppArmor or SELinux or anything like that. The port is not in use on my system. My user is a member of the "network" group if it matters. My program will bind to the socket if I run it with sudo but that's not an ideal case obviously.

Here's the code I use to create the socket and start listening:

```
    static public void Start(int port, string host)
    {
        _server = new WebSocketServer(port, IPAddress.Parse(host));
        _server.OnConnect = OnConnected;
        _server.OnDisconnect = OnDisconnect;
        _server.Start();
    }
```

"12345" is being passed as "port" and "192.168.0.11" (my local IP) is being passed as "host". I've also tried IPAddress.Any to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is already on that port?  Try `sudo netstat -anpt| grep 12345`

Comment: Yes. That command returns nothing

Comment: See if you can make a stand-alone program work just using `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener`

Comment: I just tested it in a completely new project. If I create a TcpListener on the same socket and Start() it, no exception is thrown. In the same project I tried to create a WebSocketServer and Start() it and it throws the same socket exception. This seems to suggest that the problem is with Alchemy. I'm unable to find anything that suggests Alchemy doesn't work just fine with Linux so I'm not sure what the problem is...

Comment: I wonder if Alchemy is setting a security context somehow. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5724/Understanding-NET-Code-Access-Security

Comment: Another good thing to try is to run with `strace`. Read `man strace` for details. You should be able to see the socket creation and bind attempt. Make sure the port and IP values are what you expect.

Comment: Another suggestion is to use `IPAddress.Any` instead of `host`

Comment: I tried IPAddress.Any. No difference. Here's the output of strace: http://pastebin.com/aJK5XsDj . I don't quite know how to read it though. Nothing really stands out to me...

Comment: Why not simply use `127.0.0.1` for connecting to localhost?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter. I get the same exception no matter what host I pass to it

Comment: Alchemy throws up a Flash Policy file at 843 - try turning off the flashsocketpolicy when instantiating your server.

Comment: @JackLawson - That seems to have solved the problem, thank you! If you submit it as an answer I'll accept it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alchemy throws up a Flash Policy file at 843 - try turning off the flashsocketpolicy when instantiating your server.

Answer (score 1):

This is strictly a permissions issue

> My program will bind to the socket if I run it with sudo but that's not an ideal case obviously.

This question has already been asked, in a previous post on Stackoverflow.
[mono/linux socket denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254954/mono-linux-socket-denied)

I would attempt adding the "user" to the sudo's group that will remedy it as a quick solution. if it's using ICMP or Raw Sockets it must be ran as root FYI. Double check that Alchemy isn't using this, if it is you're a little out of luck to running it with out super user permissions.

I tried posting this as a comment but it wouldn't let me, this isn't a bona fide answer.

FYI to all you down voters.